# Conflict of polarity?

Tags: raspberry-pi, polarity, attiny85

With the following circuit, would the R2 resistor not change or affect the polarity in some negative way (no pun intended)?

In the image below I added the red box as well as the red text in an effort to try and understand what is happening when the R2 resistor attaches to the +4V lead.

Can someone please explain what it is doing assuming that everything on the circuit is correct?  Note: The positive lead is switched power, so it might be on or off at any given time.

Reference webpage:[Power Control System for RPi Car PC](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Based-Power-Control-System-for-RPi-Car-PC/)

[image]

Comment: It just looks like R2 is your typical pull-down resistor for both your microcontroller and your relay. No, it wouldn't change the polarity. The worst it can do it pull down (hence the name) to an indeterminate state if the resistance is too high.

Comment: Looks like there may be two independent "grounds" there which may cause confusing voltage measurements.  Is the ATTiny ground connected to the vehicle ground?  If there is no negative power supply, you shouldn't get a negative voltage anywhere.

Comment: @PeterBennett I guess that would be the case (two independent grounds).  It's the vehicle ground that goes through a converter (DC to DC) to step down the Voltage (Zk-SJVA-4X is what I'm using).

Comment: If the R1/R2 junction is "~4V" meaning "about 4V" rather than "minus 4V", that resolves your polarity question.  Many DC-DC converters are not isolated - the input Ground is connected directly to the ouput Ground - in that case, the ATTiny Ground will be vehicle Ground, and the circuit should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R2 constitutes the lower half of a [`voltage divider`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider) used to reduce out-of-range voltages to potentials sample-able within the range of an MCU input rating.

Voltage dividers do not change polarity relative to their fixed ground.  This circuit accepts a positive input, and yields a reduced positive output.

However vehicle electrical systems are notoriously nasty, and it is a legitimate question if this design overall is sufficiently robust for such usage.

Comment: I wonder if that "-4V" is really "~4V", meaning "about 4 volts", rather than minus 4 volts?

Comment: I have some nice DC to DC converters to filter the power as well.  I'm hoping that will help out as well.  Also, the circuit is not just a design but been proven to work as per the video on the reference link.  Not sure if it will hold up for a long time but there is one way to find out.  Thanks!

Comment: @PeterBennett it is indeed.  The schematics show ~4 (image posted).

Comment: @PeterBennett it is indeed, a quite clearly if you zoom in, "~4v".  This would be a notation from the designer of the expected output voltage, though it should be noted that this is a bit high for the pi and would be undesirably activating the I/O protection diode, though probably only with a current it can tolerate given the 10K source resistor.  A designer more aware of input threshold voltages would likely have used a different division ratio.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I'm going to test all output before I hook anything up.  As I build it I will see what the output of all the leads are.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @ArvoBowen - where things like protection against the outrages of vehicle power systems are concerned, indeed, circuits work until they do not.  So the fact that it works on day one is of little meaning.

Comment: @ChrisStratton While putting this together I noticed coming off the 12V power (switched section) I added the 10K resistor (R1).  Checked the voltage and it only slightly drops to roughly 11.92 (from 12.00).  I'm still learning the basics about EE but from the schematics I was expecting a lot lower voltage (around 4v).  Does it require the circuit to be complete before I see that lines voltage around 4v?  What am I missing?

Comment: Please see the wikipedia article on voltage dividers linked in the answer.  Both R1 and R2 resistors are required.  Without R2 you have only the extremely high impedance of your meter functioning in the role of R2.